# Seed phrase of existing account in Metamask on different browser gave different address

Tags: metamask

I have Metamask installed on my browser on one machine, and I know the seed phrase of the account that it shows when I log in. Today, I installed Metamask browser extension on a different machine and entered the same seed phrase to import my existing account. However, the address shown is not the same, and so it does not show the tokens that I have in my account in the Metamask installed on my first machine.

FYI: Browser on both machines is latest Firefox version 61.0.2

The following question from 5/23/2018 seems to be a duplicate but it has no answer: [metamask shows different address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49330/metamask-shows-different-address)

Has anyone else been in this situation? What could be the reason?

Comment: Is the account you are using on the first browser the first account on Metamask? You can create multiple accounts on Metamask and can switch between them. When you instantiate Metamask on a new browser, and want to see your other accounts, you must still click `add account`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my mistake. The MetaMask plug-in on both machines has only one account but I was probably wrong in expecting the address to match. I must have created another account at some time, and saved **that** account's seed phrase. I just updated MetaMask on the first machine and found on the ***Settings*** page a button labeled **Reveal Seed Words**. After entering the password, it showed me the seed words and they were different from what I had saved and used to recover account on the other machine.

Sorry for the false alarm.